# Save and update array in a SQL Database

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I am trying to save an object (`Customer`) with an array of (`Articles`) named Sales to a database. Lets take a look at my tables:

**Table Customers**:

```
|ID|Name    |
-------------
| 1|Samuel  |
| 2|Michael |
| 3|Grace   |
```

**Table Articles**:

```
|ID|Name    |Price |
--------------------
| 1|Apple   | 1    |
| 2|Banana  | 5    |
| 3|Orange  | 2    |
```

**Table Sales**:

```
|CustomerID|ArticleID|
----------------------
|1         | 1       |
|1         | 2       |
|2         | 3       |
```

I know how to save the first time but if the array has changed (Eg. A sale was removed) I don't know how to update the Sales table.

**How to update the table when the array has changed?**

The programming language I use is C# with the System.Data.SQLite library but do not use Entity Framework right now.

I hope, you understand what I mean.

Comment: How are you connecting to your MySQL DB from your C# code?  Entity Framework?

Comment: I updated the question: No Entity Framework right now but if I need it, I can use it.

Comment: You say its MySql, but then you say you are using "System.Data.SQLite". Pick one!

Comment: Also, I know this is a shameless plug, but check out my [LayerGen 3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1000660/LayerGen), which will automatically create data layers for you in C# or VB.Net and is compatible with Sql Server, MySql and SQLite.

Comment: Sorry, took the wrong tag... It is SQLite

Comment: You should probably save the sale price in the Sales table - you wouldn't want a customer to be able to buy an item on sale, then return it for full price once the sale's over!

Comment: It is only an example. Sales and Customers is only a placeholder name

Comment: Delete all rows that should be no longer there, and insert all new rows. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I thought about that but what if my array has a more than 10k elements?

Comment: When a customer has bough 10k articles, then you need to insert 10k rows. Why is this a problem?

Comment: I thought there is a better way to do this.. but you're right it would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like CL. said:

1. **Drop all items in the array**
2. **Insert all items again**